# Set question - $ ℤ^+ = ℕ$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, definition

I am not sure whether the following statement is true: $ ℤ^+ = ℕ$

if not, why?

Thank you in advance! I appreciate your help!

Comment: It depends on the definition.

Comment: **Peano** says $0\in\mathbb{N}$, while - as far as I've always been told - $\mathbb{Z}^+$ denotes the set of strictly positive integers.

Comment: So $ℤ^+$ always means {1, 2, 3, ...}, whereas $N$ means either { 0, 1, 2, 3, ...} or { 1, 2, 3, ...}. Right?

Comment: @cherry8.8vanilla Any reasonable interpretation is one those two, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you @GitGud. I have never heard that $0$ could be a natural number, which is weird.

Comment: It is very annoying that you always need to have or give a definition of $\mathbb N$ before you can really get to work. I am afraid that this annoyance will unfortunately never come to an end. Is $0$ natural? Yes, no, yes, no, yes, no,..... As @Git Gud says: it depends on the definition. This is true, but should not be the case, unless it is a commonly accepted definition.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع: It's weird because in all these years of educating nobody mentioned to me that $0$ could actually be treated as a natural number.

Comment: @drhab: It's exactly how I feel about this. I think that they should finally decide on whether $0$ is or isn't a natural number. This question is really causing a lot of confusion around people.

Comment: @cherry8.8vanilla The reasonable thing is for $0$ to be a natural number. But since analysts are lazy, they choose to start $\mathbb N$ at $1$ so they don't have to exclude $0$ every time.

Comment: @GitGud: Thank you, that explains a lot.

Comment: [Also an exact duplicate of this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807328/does-the-set-of-natural-numbers-mathbbn-include-0).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My apologies for not noticing that before. Thank you for notifying me and others about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the definitions.

$\mathbf{N}$ usually includes zero and $\mathbf{Z}^+$ usually does not. But occasionally people define $\mathbf{N}$ to exclude zero or $\mathbf{Z}^+$ to include zero, or both.

I often use $\mathbf{Z}^>$ (respectively $\mathbf{Z}^{\geq}$) for excluding (resp. including) zero, as I've never seen any ambiguity with those.

(or sometimes the longer forms $\mathbf{Z}^{>0}$ and $\mathbf{Z}^{\geq 0})$

Comment: Is $0$ an even or an odd number?

Comment: @cherry: Even, because it is divisible by $2$.

Comment: But it's divisible by any number, or not? (by $3,5,7,9,$ etc. as well, and those are odd numbers $(2k-1)$)

Comment: @cherry8.8vanilla: When checking whether a number is even or not, we just care about its divisibility by 2. We don't care if it's divisible by 3, 4, etc... or not.

Comment: @user49685: Thank you for explaining that to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of convention. Always keep in mind that "positive" $\neq $ "non-negative". I like to consider $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, because of the notation $\mathbb{N}^*$, which means $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. And indeed $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mathbb{N}^*$ are isomorphic.

Comment: ... but also keep in mind that people will often say "positive" when they really mean "non-negative", so you have to be on guard to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Hurkyl With 'people' you mean 'analysts'.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbb{N} \!\,$:= {$1,2,3,4,5,...$} and ℤ+ ={$1,2,3,4,5,...$}, then we can show that $\mathbb{N} \!\,$ is [isomorphic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isomorphism.html) to ℤ+.

So we can think of them as "equal".

Obviously, if you define $\mathbb{N} \!\,$ or ℤ+ otherwise then this won't hold.

Usually, [$\mathbb{N} \!\,$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) is defined not to include $0$ as originally stated.

Comment: Usually is defined not to include $0$? If anything, usually it is defined to include $0$.

Comment: From my experience, it is defined without $0$.